# Find all (k, d)-motifs in a collection of DNA strings

Tags: python, string

Basically, the question is to ask to find out all possible motifs (k-mers long) with no more than d mismatches among a collection of strings DNA. I can write the code below to find all motifs (k, d) for one string DNA. I don't know how to modify my code when it comes out multi-line of strings DNA.

**Sample Input:**

> k = 3, d = 1
>
> ATTTGGC
>
> TGCCTTA
>
> CGGTATC
>
> GAAAATT

**Sample Output:**

> ATA
>
> ATT
>
> GTT
>
> TTT

```
import collections

    kmer = 5;
    in_genome = "GGGGCTTCACAGCGCCCCTACAATACAATAGCCCTCGAATACCTACTTGCCACTATGTTCGGCGTCATTACATACGACCCGCATGCTCGGCAGTATGTCTCTACTCAGGATCCCTCAATATTACTTACGCCAATATGTCTAAGGTTTAGA";
    in_mistake = 1;
    out_result = [];
    mismatch_list = []

    def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
        # Return the Hamming distance between equal-length sequences
        if len(s1) != len(s2):
            raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
        else:
            return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))

    for i in xrange(len(in_genome)-kmer + 1):
        v = in_genome[i:i + kmer]
        out_result.append(v)

    for t_kmer in set(out_result):
        for s_kmer in out_result:
            if hamming_distance(t_kmer, s_kmer) <= in_mistake:
                mismatch_list.append(t_kmer)

    mismatch_count = collections.Counter(mismatch_list)

    print mismatch_count
```

Comment: what is the question plz?

Comment: can you please elaborate on the meaning of `d`? Define a mismatch

Comment: You can concatenate all these lines to the string in_genome

Comment: @ Aprillion The question is "Given a collection of strings Dna and an integer d, a k-mer is a (k,d)-motif if it appears in every string from Dna with at most d mismatches. 
Implanted Motif Problem: Find all (k, d)-motifs in a collection of strings.
Input: A collection of strings Dna, and integers k and d.
Output: All (k, d)-motifs in Dna.

Comment: @ Pynchia The d means the number of mismatch nucleotides in a given string. For example, the sample pattern is AAAA, if d=0, we must found another AAAA in a string DNA which is the exact same as the sample pattern. If d <= 1, our results could not only be AAAA, but also includes AAAT, ATAA etc., if they are found in the a string DNA sequence.

Comment: @user5893556 I think that will generate a different object for analysis. I tried to concatenate all four strings together as one string and they come out a different result.

Comment: I think the "motif" tag is incorrect - this question has nothing to do with X/Motif GUI libraries

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be to switch the code from using internal variables to reading input from a file.  You can't just concatenate the file's DNA strands together and run it as before as that changes the result where the ends of the strands meet.  You also have to process the first line of the input differently from the others as it contains program parameters and the rest are raw data:

```
import re
import sys
import collections

mismatch_list = []

def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    """ Returns the Hamming distance between equal-length sequences """
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
    return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))

with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:

    kmer = None
    in_mistake = None

    parameters = file.readline().rstrip()  # first line of file has parameters

    matchobj = re.search(r"k\s*=\s*(\d+)", parameters)
    if matchobj:
        kmer = int(matchobj.group(1))

    matchobj = re.search(r"d\s*=\s*(\d+)", parameters)
    if matchobj:
        in_mistake = int(matchobj.group(1))

    assert kmer is not None and in_mistake is not None, "file parameters misread"

    for sequence in file:  # subsequent lines of file are DNA strands
        sequence = sequence.rstrip()
        if not sequence:
            continue  # ignore blank lines

        result = []

        for i in range(len(sequence) - kmer + 1):
            v = sequence[i:i + kmer]
            result.append(v)

        for t_kmer in set(result):
            for s_kmer in result:
                if hamming_distance(t_kmer, s_kmer) <= in_mistake:
                    mismatch_list.append(t_kmer)

mismatch_count = collections.Counter(mismatch_list)

print(mismatch_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The next step would be to loop over all the single lines / strings / strands and store their results in a set. Afterwards you have to get the intersection of all the sets.
The following code gives correct results as required above and in the online course Bioinformatics I.
Use the following on sample dataset, however to get results on larger datasets, do comment the extra output, so that terminal does not spend much time in printing excessive requirements

```
def HammingDistance(a, b):
    a = a.lower()
    b = b.lower()
    hd = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] != b[i]:
            hd += 1
    return(hd)

def Suffix(Pattern): 
    return Pattern[1:]

def Neighbors(Pattern, d): 
    if d == 0: 
        return {Pattern}
    if len(Pattern) == 1: 
        return {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'}
    Neighborhood = set()
    SuffixNeighbors = Neighbors(Suffix(Pattern), d)
    # for each string Text from SuffixNeighbors:
    for Text in SuffixNeighbors:
        if HammingDistance(Suffix(Pattern), Text) < d:
            # for each nucleotide x:
            for x in 'ATCG':
                # add x • Text to Neighborhood
                Neighborhood.add(x+Text)
        else:
            # add FirstSymbol(Pattern) • Text to Neighborhood
            Neighborhood.add(Pattern[0]+Text)

    return Neighborhood

# MotifEnumeration(Dna, k, d)
#     Patterns ← an empty set
#     for each k-mer Pattern in Dna
#         for each k-mer Pattern’ differing from Pattern by at most d mismatches
#             if Pattern' appears in each string from Dna with at most d mismatches
#                 add Pattern' to Patterns
#     remove duplicates from Patterns
#     return Patterns

def MotifEnumeration(Dna, k, d):
    print("Starting Brute-Force Search for Candidate Motif / Motif Enumeration...\n\n\n")
    motifs_candidate_all = []
    strand_kmers = {}

    for strand in Dna: 
        print("Starting Search with Dna String: ", strand)
        for w in range(len(strand)+1-k):
            pattern = strand[w:w+k]
            print(f"Along the window in {strand}, the k-mer is {pattern}.")
            pattern_neighbors = Neighbors(pattern, d)
            for pn in pattern_neighbors:
                motifs_candidate_all.append(pn)
            print(f"Generated and processed Neighbors of {pattern}: {pattern_neighbors}")
    
    print("Completed the generation of k-mers library\n\n\n")

    for strand in Dna:
        print("Started the finding of each kmer from kmer library, in Dna strands")
        strand_data = []
        for n in motifs_candidate_all:
            print("Current Motif: ", n)
            for i in range(len(strand)+1-k):
                print("Starting a window")
                c = strand[i:i+k]
                nbs = Neighbors(c, d)
                print(f"Comparing {n} with neighbors of {c}, the neighbors are: {nbs}")
                if n in nbs:
                    strand_data.append(n)
                    print(f"Found {n} in {nbs}...")
        strand_kmers[strand] = set(strand_data)
        print(f"Storing Data of strand {strand} in dictionary. The data is an array converted to set: {strand_data} ")
        
    print("Data of Strands and KMers. This shows all the kmers with a hamming distance of d found in a Dna Strand")
    print(strand_kmers)

    strand_sets = list(strand_kmers.values())
    print("Getting values from Dictionary")
    print("The Values are: ")
    print(strand_sets)

    for i in range(50):
        print("Finalizing Results", "."*i)
    res = set.intersection(*strand_sets)
    print("Intersecting the sets contaning data from each strand.")

    print("Result: ")
    print(res)
    print(len(res))

    print("Script written by Muhammad Abdullah Nabeel")
    return res


sample = ['ATTTGGC', 'TGCCTTA' ,'CGGTATC', 'GAAAATT']
res = MotifEnumeration(sample, 3, 1)

#sample = ['CTAGGATGGCTCCGCTTATTTCTGT', 'TAGGGCCTTAAAGTCCTAGACTGGC', 'ACATGGATGCATGTATTGGACTTGC', 'CTTGAACAAATCTGATTTCTCCGTA' ,'GAGACCTCGCCTGCCCTGTTGACCA', 'AGCAGAATAACTAGGGGCTATCCCA']
#res = MotifEnumeration(sample, 5, 2)

print(res)
for i in res:
    print(i)
```